# Android canvas rotation: need to rotate *by* x degrees not *to* x degrees

Tags: android, rotation, android-canvas

The documentation for the rotate methods in Canvas states that the degrees parameter is "the amount to rotate, in degrees".  However, in my experience this is misleading.  For example, if I call rotate(45) when my bitmap is in the canonically upright orientation (i.e. theta = 0, which is at 12:00) then the bitmap dutifully rotates 45 degrees with respect to 0.  If I make a second call to rotate(45), the image does not [appear to] move.  If I then make a call to rotate(-45), the bitmap does not return to its original orientation but is instead rotated -45 degrees with respect to 0.  In other words, the degrees parameter is absolute ("rotate to 45 degrees"), not relative ("rotate by 45 degrees") as the documentation implies.  This is precisely what I don't want.

From a given orientation, I want to be able to rotate my bitmap *BY* +/- x degrees, where + is of course a clockwise rotation.  One way to fake this, I suppose, would be to make wherever I rotate to the "new 0" (i.e. it effectively occupies 12:00) for the purposes of the next rotation.  My question is: how do I do this, or, is there a better way to accomplish what I want?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One simple approach would be to store the last rotation as a variable and +/- next rotation to it - watching of course you don't go beyond 360.

Comment: You can check the upper bound with a simple modulus 360 operator  ;)

Comment: @eric - yes very nice. Didn't think of that.

Comment: @dbryson: Yes that is what I am doing already as a kind of hack.  The problem is that I may well have to go beyond +/- 360.

Comment: @Urthas one reason I can think for the canvas.rotate working this way is because the Sensor service gives you the absolute degrees of rotation.  As for a solution to your problem, I always start with the simplest thing that will work :-).  That's not necessarily a "hack". But I don't understand how you will have to go beyond 360.

Comment: The other thing is that I always want the smallest angle between successive rotations.  So, if the first rotation was to -170 and the second is to 170, I want to rotate by 20 degrees counter-clockwise (i.e. to -190) rather than |240|.  You might think of it as an infinite number of degrees.  The new position is only important insofar as it provides a minimum difference from the old.

Comment: It sounds like then even if the canvas.rotate worked on relative position it would not work as you want.  So either way you'll need to store some of the previous rotations and do a little math to decide what rotation to do next.

Comment: I'm not explaining this well.  Forget infinite degrees.  There would be no need if every time I rotated to some absolute coordinate, it became 0.  In that case, there is no coordinate that cannot, as you say, be specified within +- 360 degrees.  I have an upright image on the screen.  When the user touches the screen, the image should rotate to be in line with that position.  Rotation will be **animated**.  There are two directions to animate to any position: clockwise and ccw.  I want to animate from the previous coordinate to the current coordinate in the "right" direction.

Answer (score 1):

I think `canvas.setMatrix(canvas.getMatrix())` will 'save' all the changes you have made thereby making wherever you've rotated the 'new 0'. But dbryson's suggestion is the economical one for the purpose you mention.

Comment: This is very interesting and I'll have to play with it.  After a few hours hacking at cached rotations per dbryson &co, I am still running hard into situations where I'm near +-360 and then go beyond.  Either I'll figure this out or I'll decide that it's more complicated than it absolutely needs to be.  Thanks everyone for your help